# UnboundError From dict.get()

Tags: python, discord.py

Why Would dataList = players.get(str(ctx.author.id)) Throw the Error "Local Variable players defined in enclosing scope on line players = json.load(f) referenced before assignment"?

```
with open('profiles.json') as f:
    players = json.load(f)

@bot.command(aliases = ['s'])
@commands.cooldown(1,10,commands.BucketType.user)
async def sell(ctx):
    dataList = players.get(str(ctx.author.id))
    amount = dataList[3]
    item = dataList[2]
    multi = dataList[1]

    await ctx.send(f"You Currently Have {amount} {item} How Many Would You Like To Sell? (Type Abort To Stop This Action)")

    message = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=10, check=lambda m: m.author.id == ctx.author.id)

    if int(message.content) <= amount:
        await ctx.send(f"You Sold {message.content} {item} For {amount*multi}SH (+5 Rep)")
        dataList[5] += 5
        players[str(ctx.author.id)] = dataList

        out_file = open("profiles.json", "w")
        json.dump(players, out_file)
        out_file.close()

    else:
        await ctx.send("WE GOT A SWINDLER, GET HIM! (-10 Rep)")

        dataList[5] -= 10
        players[str(ctx.author.id)] = dataList

        out_file = open("profiles.json", "w")
        json.dump(players, out_file)
        out_file.close()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Which line is getting the error? `players =` or `dataList =`?

Comment: Is all this code nested inside another function?

Comment: the error line is dataList = players.get(str(ctx.author.id)).

Comment: and the code is just in the sell function

Comment: There's no assignment of `players`  anywhere in the function, so I don't see how that error is possible. It should be accessed as a global variable.

Comment: Are you going to add the full traceback?

Comment: im sorry for responding so late but i think i got it working